# Which Reason to my Code Show error : Forbidden?

Tags: android, api, okhttp

I try to send data through API using `Okhttp` but show me an error,

> Error is "Forbidden"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkaOB.png)

In Image Also Show JSON Object which is I Try to  Post,
Require Object formate and I Post Object formate is Same No there Mistake. Where am I making mistake?

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try{

                OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, String.valueOf(object));

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(SendTeam)
                        .post(body)
                        .build();

                Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                String result = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();

                JSONObject ob = new JSONObject(result);
                Log.d("myteampro", ""+ob);

                Message message = new Message();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("ms", result);
                message.setData(bundle);

                mHandler.sendMessage(message);

            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that you need to add some kind of authorization or token to access to post to the url in the request.

You can check the response code.  If I am right it should be 403.

Something like this:

```
                    request = new Request.Builder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Token " + token)
                            .url(myURL)
                            .post(body)
                            .build();
```

but your .header() line might require different words/labels.